# How to send gziped xml content using curl and php

Tags: php, xml, curl, gzip

My code like that as below, but I cannot get the response successfully. Is anything wrong with my code?

**Code:**

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8','Content-Encoding: gzip',);
$gziped_xml_content = gzencode($xml_content);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $the_web_service_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $gziped_xml_content);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 4):

The code is correct. I mean the curl is ok. The error is elsewhere. Your code returns following `verbose` output which implies the code is correct.

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: XXX <- some digits
```

**Scenario#1**: It can be the server can not handle gzip data. So its throwing you error.

**Scenario#2**: May be the XML you are sending that has incorrect format, and server failed to parse it and throw you error.

**Scenario#3**: May be the data you are sending its too large(content length > 1024) for a normal curl post. That case you have to use `multipart/form-data` form posting.

But before anything, run the curl code with VERBOSE mode enable and it will help you to debug this yourself.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

Finally, `I cannot get the response successfully` is not a good point to make in your question. Rather using the error you are getting along with more problematic info will help the others who want to help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer very much! I think there is a higher possibility for the Scenario1.I will try to get more information.Thank you again!