# how to compress(gzip) body of a request in guzzle 6

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

need to send compressed (gzip) body to a server

e.g.

```
    protected function postOrPutData($method, $data, $type, $uri = null, array $options = [])
    {
        $requestBody = $this->serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

        $request  = new Request($method, $uri, [], $requestBody);
        $response = $this->httpClient->send($request, $options);

        return $this->serializer->deserialize((string) $response->getBody(), $type, 'json');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can get inspiration also from [similar question about pure cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22554008/how-to-send-gziped-xml-content-using-curl-and-php).

Try to use this custom setting with Guzzle (I assume that you are using it with cURL handler):

```
$options['curl'] = [CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'];

$request  = new Request($method, $uri, [], $requestBody);
$response = $this->httpClient->send($request, $options);
```

Comment: php documention says that CURLOPT_ENCODING enables gzip for **response** not request.

Comment: @Stalinko, you are right, the answer is wrong. Standard [gzcompress](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) function should do the work.

Comment: correct, but that's not enough. You must also add `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: @Stalinko , can you add example how did you solve this. Also want to send to server compressed json data in body. But can't find how to do it in Guzzle 6.